# Applying pushObject() to model

Tags: ember.js

This [Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/7fdadc269c1f64ab73f790f7206da013) is a simple Ember application that tracks the attendance of employees.

It consists of two columns of employee names. On arrival or departure, each employee clicks their name to sign in or out.

The problem is that employees cannot currently sign out.

I'm seeing the error

```
TypeError: internalModel.getRecord is not a function
```

for this line

```
this.get(b).pushObject(item);
```

I think it's because in this case, `b` = `Ember.computed.alias('model')` which isn't an array and therefore `pushObject` can't be applied. Right?

I suppose I need to know how to map my `model` to an `array` or perhaps try a different approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert the model into an array in the route like this:

```
model() {
  return this.store.findAll('employee').then(emps => emps.toArray());
}
```

After making this change employees can can successfully be clicked "in" and "out" but you'll need to check that the rest of your code is still operating as intended.